# chmod and chown not working in sudo called script

Tags: shell-script, sudo, chmod, chown

Based on this [Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/498792/git-prime-hub-website-deployment-documentroot-changes-save-fine-but-permission), my git user has permission in sudoers to run a wrapper script to move files into my webroot with git.

Everything is working fine except for the chmod and chown lines. After the script has run, the files are still root:root instead of apache:apache.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo
echo "**** Pulling changes into Prime [Hub's post-update hook]"
echo
cd /usr/local/apache/htdocs || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull hub master
exec /usr/libexec/git-core/git-update-server-info
chmod -R 0644 /usr/local/apache/htdocs
chown -R apache:apache /usr/local/apache/htdocs
```

Since the script is running as root, why wouldn't the chmod and chown commands be working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The chmod line is never reached as you can easily check by inserting `touch /root/checkfile` directly above. `exec` does not return into the script. I must be the last command in a script (or script's branch).